Return null or string in gdscript
I want a function that can return something, or not, in gdscript
func test() -> String | null:
  return null if random() > 0.5 else "hi"

The syntax above is not real.  How do I make a return type of String or null?

I see an open proposal for adding nullable static types to GDScript with a pull request implementing the idea that appears to be in active development, but not yet released in a mainline version.
